# Weird Swift 2.0 if/else statement error

Tags: if-statement, swift2

This code works perfectly fine in swift version 1, however when I updated to swift 2.0 it gives me an error:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var inpute: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var output: UILabel!

    @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
       print(inpute.text)
       let randomnum = arc4random_uniform(6)
       let guessblank = Int(inpute.text!)
       if guessblank != nil {
            if Int(randomnum) == guessblank {
               output.text = "you got it correct"
            }
            else { output.text = "Wrong number"
            }
        // here is where the error is. It tells me "Expected                 
       // expression" and "missing condition in if statement" 
       else { output.text = "please input a number"

            }
         }
     }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: That code wouldn't have compiled in Swift 1 either, so don't claim that it did.

Answer (score 0):

You have a brace out-of-place — your first "else" statement completed the inner "if", so it needed a closing brace there, and one less closing brace after your second "else". Assuming this is the logic you want, the following code has no errors:

```
@IBOutlet var inpute: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var output: UILabel!

@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
    print(inpute.text)
    let randomnum = arc4random_uniform(6)
    let guessblank = Int(inpute.text!)
    if guessblank != nil {
        if Int(randomnum) == guessblank {
            output.text = "you got it correct"
        }
        else { output.text = "Wrong number"
        }
    }
    else { output.text = "please input a number"
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```